# Recursive function to generate flat array from hierarchical array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

What I've tried to do for the past hour is a function that will let me generate a flat array of the same pages, but with the children having their parents title before them
what I could do so far is get 1 level of the parents, I need the logic behind this and I can do the code, the main point is to have an array to fetch in select menu 
i.e:

```
Parent 
parent / Sub 1
Parent / Sub 1 / Sub 2
Parent 2
parent 2 / Sub 1
Parent 2 / Sub 1 / Sub 2
```

My array looks like this :

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
        [object]=>menuObject
        [title]=>title
        [parent_id]=>parent_id

        [children]=>array(

          [0] => Array (
            [object]=>menuObject
            [title]=>title
            [parent_id]=>parent_id
            [children]=>''
         )

      )
   )
);
```

the array I need will look like:

```
    Array(
        [14]=>'parent / sub / sub 1'
         //[ID]=>[Title]
    )
```

Comment: It's funny, someone tried the exact same thing yesterday :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190772/how-to-create-an-html-dropdown-from-the-recursive-array-in-php/30190997#30190997

This will more likely fit your need

Comment: thanks guys I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after pretty long time I figured out a way to do it with 2 functions, 
the first to flatten the array, and the other to find out the path, though I had to Query the DB to make it

```
public function parseSelectArray($tree)
    {
        $return=array();
        foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
           //The other function call to create the path
           $return[$key]=Controller_Admin_Pages::createPath($key);
        }
        return empty($return) ? null : $return;
    }
    public function createPath($id) {
        //Query the page, though I could get the value from the array.
        $page=Model_Page::find($id);

        if($page->idparent == 0) {
            $name = $page->title;
            return $name;
        } else {
            $name = $page->title;
            return Controller_Admin_Pages::createPath($page->idparent). " / ".$name;
        }
    }
```